# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with sprite sheet

Tags: java, android, andengine

I keep getting this error with andengine when using a sprite sheet.

Can anyone explain what i means?

```
08-30 13:31:50.053: E/AndroidRuntime(9643): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=12
```

here is where the error is occuring at.

```
    pItem.setCurrentTileIndex(MathUtils.random(0, pItem.getTileCount()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `MathUtils.random` is inclusive, which means that in your example (array of size 12), it will generate a number from 0 to 12, *including* 12. Try changing your code to:

```
pItem.setCurrentTileIndex(MathUtils.random(0, pItem.getTileCount() - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

try:
`pItem.setCurrentTileIndex(MathUtils.random(0, pItem.getTileCount()-1));`

`getTileCount()` likely returns the # of tiles, so indexes would be that minus 1.